# Firebase - is it possible to check user's connection status from a private server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello guys,

Using Firebase on a mobile app, I'm calling for my server to sign uploads to a third party service. In that script, I will make several checks before granting the user the wanted signature. One I would like to make but can't figure out how is to check if this user is currently connected to Firebase.

Is it possible ?

Thanks ahead !

Comment: Use the information in `.info/connected` to determine if the user is connected to Firebase and pass it along when the app calls your API. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for this fast answer. It's a very interesting feature, and I could use it... But it looks very "hackable" to me, since anyone can send whatever he wants to my endpoint. The point of checking this is mostly to avoid unauthorized people to upload files linked to a part of my app they don't have access to. That's why I wanted to check connection state from the server side.

Comment: Jeremy, .info/connected is a local meta setting used to monitor you local connection state, not data stored in Firebase. Nobody can write anything to it on your behalf.

Comment: That's what I said. That's why I asked for a way to check if a user is connected by just having his ID. I guess I will just have to check in his /user/id/online, but I would have prefered for a meta way to do it. Thanks guys !